# Erro Uncaught exception PDOException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014

Tags: php, mysql, query, pdo

Tenho um código que funciona perfeitamente no servidor local wampserver, trata-se de uma consulta intercalando os resultado o problema é que ao terminar o site e hospedar o mesmo recebo um erro.

O código é esse:

```
$conn->exec('SET @orderA := 0; SET @orderB := 0;');
$q = $conn->prepare("
SELECT id, voz
FROM (
    SELECT id, voz
    ,IF(voz = 'voz-feminina', @orderA := @orderA + 1, IF(voz = 'voz-masculina', @orderB := @orderB + 1, null)) AS idx
    FROM musica
    WHERE audio = 'pop'
) AS a
ORDER BY idx, voz;
");
$q->execute();
while ($linha = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $linha['voz'];
}
```

E o erro é esse:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using
>   PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever
>   going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting
>   the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in
>   D:\web\localuser\www\novo\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\web\localuser\www\novo\index.php(15): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   {main} thrown in D:\web\localuser\www\novo\index.php on line 15

O que pode ser?

Comment: O próprio erro sugere uma edição: "Considere usar fetchAll()". 
$linha = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: tentei mudar seguindo a resposta do erro mais sem sucesso. acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: você tentou executar o SQL direto no seu SGBD?

Comment: sim executei e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Antes desse código tem alguma outra consulta? poderia colocar parte dela na pergunta.

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Opa tudo bem.  não sei ao certo se foi uma solução, mais pedi para o provedor mudar a versão do php para a ultima versão e resolveu o problema. mais esse código não funciona na versão antiga que é a 5.2.XX  do php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pessoa. obrigado a todos pelo esforços. quando estava desenvolvendo este código em php em servidor local usava a versão do php 5.5.12 e porem o mesmo funcionava perfeitamente, meus problemas começou quando subi o código para um servidor de hospedagem com a versão do php 5.2.xx ai apresentou este problema. quando percebi a diferença de versões pedi uma migração para um servidor com a versão php 5.5.12 ou superior, e pronto problema solucionado. não sei se isso foi realmente uma solução ou uma gambiarra. mais agora esta tudo rodando perfeitamente. Obrigado a todos os programadores do stackoverflow, vocês é nota 10.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
$conn->exec('SET @orderA := 0; SET @orderB := 0;');

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);

$q = $conn->prepare("
SELECT id, voz
FROM (
    SELECT id, voz
    ,IF(voz = 'voz-feminina', @orderA := @orderA + 1, IF(voz = 'voz-masculina', @orderB := @orderB + 1, null)) AS idx
    FROM musica
    WHERE audio = 'pop'
) AS a
ORDER BY idx, voz;
");
$q->execute();

$resultados = new ArrayIterator($q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

foreach($resultados as $res) {
    echo $res->voz;
}
```

Comment: mesmo erro. quando eu tiro a primeira linha mostra o resultado mais não intercalado

Comment: Vi algo parecido no github e foi solucionado colocando $conn->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);

Answer (score 0):

Caso tenha uma consulta antes do `exec()`, feche ele antes de iniciar a próxima com [closeCursor()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php), isso é recomendado no caso de multiplas consultas e no uso de `fetch()`.

```
$stmt->closeCursor(); //fecha a consulta anterior
$conn->exec('SET @orderA := 0; SET @orderB := 0;');
```

Comment: Problema resolvido. código não funciona na versão antiga do php.

Comment: @wildson, cria uma resposta descrevendo melhor os detalhes de como resolver o problema.